# Recursive algorithm for adding numbers from 1 to n with O(1) time complexity

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recursion

So I have a recursive algorithm which sums up the numbers from 1 to n **plus one** (hence the return 1):

```
public static int S(int n) {
    if(n < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n + S(n-1);
    }
}
```

This algorithm has a time complexity of O(n).

Is it possible to derive an algorithm which produces the same output as the one shown above but with a constant time complexity of O(1)?

Comment: [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum $1+2+3+\cdots+n$ is equal to $n(n+1)/2$; hence, the following function would return the same output:

```
Function S(n):
    if n < 0, then return 1
    Else return n(n+1)/2 + 1
```

It takes time $O(1)$, but does not make recursive function calls.  Generally, a recursive function would take linear time, unless you are willing to consider contrived versions like the code shown below, where the depth of recursion is bounded by a constant:

```
Function S(n):
    If n is even, then return 1+n(n+1)/2
    Else return n + S(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The method was invented by Carl Friedrich Gauss, aged 6.  It’s simple. Add the first and the last number. Add the second and the second-to-last number. Then the third and third to last. And so on. Find the pattern.

Comment: Thank you! How would the Gauss sum be calculated in a recursive way? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @maxig https://physicsdb.com/sum-natural-numbers/

Comment: It’s one addition and one multiplication to get the complete result. No recursion anywhere in sight.

Comment: The Gauss story might be apocryphal.

Answer (score 1):

Any algorithm that has $O(1)$ complexity must be extremely simple.

In your case, there is just a known closed form for this summation, so your program can return it within $O(1)$ (well technically this is assuming that addition, multiplication and division can be done in constant time)